# Matlab plot scatterplot with intermediate coordinates

Tags: matlab, svd

This is an exam task that I have. Lets say I have a 200x6 matrix where 200 people voted a movie with respect to 6 questions, each on a continous [0, 1]-scale (0: disagree, 1: agree).
To get a useful overview of the 6-dimensional dataset I want to plot the rank-2 approximation of the data. First I do the rank 2 approximation:

```
A = (200, 6); %some data 
[U, S, V] = svd(A);
Ak = U(:, 1:2) * S(1:2, 1:2) * V(:, 1:2)';
```

I want to plot this approximation as a 2D scatterplot with a "*"-mark per survey participant using either U or V coordinates as intermediate coordinates depending on how my data is organized.. The problem is that I don't know what intermediate coordinates mean, and I can't find a good explanation anywhere. Wonder if someone could help, eventually providing a small code example. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, intermediate axes are (ortogonal) linear combinations of your data (along maximun explained variance, a.k.a. principal components).

If most of data have similar shape (e.g. [5 4 3 2 1 0] pattern), then the first component will be similar to this shape/vector, since the variance arount it is minimal (or: variance along it is maximal). Next components as well minimize the rest of variance in ortogonal planes.

So, the answer is: **principal components 1 and 2**.

And more precicely: first intermediate coordinate value can be understood as magnitude of that "first main pattern" in a single data sample.